# 2d array not storing info correctly in a loop in c

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am trying to return a 2d array to my main function from a separate function where I am inputting some data that I calculate within the function. However, the second row is not storing the info correctly. If I remove the loop it stores correctly but I need a loop to avoid writing the same code over and over. Sample code:

```
double** func1(int int1, double double1, double double2, float float1){


double** pntrArray;
int i;

pntrArray = calloc((length * 12), sizeof(double*));

for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
 pntrArray[i] = calloc(2, sizeof(double));

int r = 0;

do{
 //calculations here
 pntrArray[0][r] = data calculated;
 pntrArray[1][r] = data calculated;
 r++;
}while(r < int1);
```

I have tried different types of loops and I cannot get it to enter the correct data. I am just beginning to learn c so this may be a very simple fix.

Comment: Instead of stressing out and using two dimensional arrays, which are honestly not worth the fuss, just use a single `rows * cols` size and emulate 2D access later with `col + rows * width`.

Comment: Tip: Use `for (int r = 0; r < int1; ++r)` for loops in preference to this far more verbose `do ... while`, but also don't use names like `int1` for arguments. Give that a meaningful name.

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions are swapped or misused:

This allocates pointers for `length*12` rows, but later code suggests you want just two rows:

```
pntrArray = calloc((length * 12), sizeof(double*));
```

Then this allocates space for two elements in each of two rows, but the earlier code suggests you want `length*12` elements in each of two rows:

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
 pntrArray[i] = calloc(2, sizeof(double));
```

Later, this works with some number of elements in just two rows:

```
 pntrArray[0][r] = data calculated;
 pntrArray[1][r] = data calculated;
```